# Routing issue when using ASP MVC 2 areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp mvc 2 areas. I am trying to set up the project such that when the web site is launced it calls one of the controllers in my areas instead of the default home page.

When I update the routes in the Global.asax file, it doesn't seem to work.

It is giving me an error since it is looking only in the views directory and not in the Areas folder. How can i force it to look into the Areas folder too?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a custom ViewLocator as described here: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/30/partitioning-an-aspnet-mvc-application-into-separate-areas/

Comment: Since asp mvc 2 supports the areas concept, i would assume that it would be inbuilt and i wouldn't need to add custom view locator. 
I am having the problem only if i define it as a default route in the global.asax that it unable to resolve the view information.